# Which post on SE chat has the most stars?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

Is there any way to find out which chat post across the entire chat.SE network (all rooms, all users) has the most stars?

<sub>I solemnly swear that the intention of this question is **not** so that I can find it and clear the stars on it.</sub>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got curious.

The top-starred message on chat.SE is, funnily enough...

> [image: okay seriously stop abusing stars]

on chat.meta.SE:

> [image: /users/current is the Hero of Stack Overflow]

and finally, on chat.SO:

> [image: Star this if you want Uncle Gordon for moderator]

(Gordon did, in fact, become a moderator in the 2013 election.)

Comment: Who is that hero guy?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current). He's just the best.

Comment: I remember that "hero" comment from a while ago. Still amusing. The fact that a PCG chatroom has more stars than either of the other two is kind of astonishing, though.

Comment: Any way for us mortals to find it, or did you have to dig in the database itself? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No public way short of looking through starred lists in every room.